# In PL/SQL what is a difference between a cursor and a reference cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql

As per my knowledge, a cursor is used to process SQL statements in private area and we can use it further. A Ref cursor is defining a cursor at the spot where it is needed. Please correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: A good link for cursors is http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html

Comment: Also, Tom Kyte, the Oracle Guru, provides a great explanation: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:14188501024541

Answer (score 6):

A cursor is really any SQL statement that runs DML (select, insert, update, delete) on your database.

A ref cursor is a pointer to a result set. This is normally used to open a query on the database server, then leave it up to the client to fetch the result it needs. A ref cursor is also a cursor, though normally ther term cursor is used when discussing static SQL.

Ref cursors are typically used to change the where clause of a query, based on user input. For example, this function, either opens a query to the `emp` table or the `dept` table, depending upon what the user has selected:

```
create or replace function f (input in varchar2) return sys_refcursor as
  cur sys_refcursor;
begin

  if input = 'EMP' then
    open cur for select * from emp;
  elsif input = 'DEPT' then
    open cur for select * from dept;
  end if;
  return cur;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Static cursor is associated with single SQL query.
It is not flexible that is why use dynamic cursor called as **ref cursor** to use same cursor for different queries.